# Clear all entities of core data DB except one entity

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data

I need to clear all the Core data entity data in the CoreData but not one Entity. i.e that one entity should not be deleted. One way is to clear entity by entity and skin the one needed. But Can we backup or keep the entity in RAM, clear all Db and re-save the entity. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can batch delete entities with a `NSBatchDeleteRequest`, the code assumes `managedObjectContext` as the current managed object context:

```
let entityNamesToDelete = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]
let persistentStoreCoordinator = managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator!

do {
    for entityName in entityNamesToDelete {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)

        try persistentStoreCoordinator.execute(deleteRequest, with: managedObjectContext)

    }
    try managedObjectContext.save()

} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: I have around 30 entities but i need to restore 1 entity. Is there any approach to keep it in RAM and re save it after deleting the core data.

Comment: Yes, of course. Add `Codable` conformance, make a backup in JSON format, delete the contents of the entity and recreate the records. The effort depends on the number of involved relationships.

Comment: it has 6 tables in relation. Is it easy to convert to json and again making it to managed object ?

Comment: It depends on the concrete model graph